# Expected BOF record for XLRD when first line is redundant

Tags: jupyter-notebook, python-3.5, xlrd

I came across the problem when I tried to use xlrd to import an .xls file and create dataframe using python.

Here is my file format:

[xls file format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVEKQ.png)

When I run:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import xlrd

for filename in os.listdir("."):
    if filename.startswith("report_1"):
       df = pd.read_excel(filename)
```

It's showing "XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'Report g'"
I am pretty sure nothing wrong with xlrd (version 1.0.0) because when I remove the first row, dataframe can be created. 
Wonder if there is any way that i can load the original file format?

Answer (score 0):

Try following that accounts for a header line:

```
df = pd.read_excel(filename, header=0)
```